# Storing 1000 cells of formulas into a variable VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hi everyone is there a way of storing range 1000 cells of formulas into declared variable which is variant. Whilst I have been able store 1000 cells which are values into a variable. I am keen to know how you can do this with formulas and formating, large range of formulas using VBA.

Answer (score 1):

You do it just as the same as with values for example

```
Dim v As Variant
v = Range("B1:B3").Formula
```

This wll give you the fornulas as string in an array.

At least that's how I understand your question.

Comment: so you are telling me that I have been missing formula on the range that I have selected. What about storing the formatting also in the variable.

Comment: How should I know? You did not post any code so I am just guessing.

Comment: Storax thanks the above worked, how would you take the formatting such as coloured cells and store it in a variable. Why is it you can not declare your variable as range but a variant

Comment: The variable is declared as variant because that's what you wanted to _Hi everyone is there a way of storing range 1000 cells of formulas into declared variable which is variant._ I suggest to read [this](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-range-cells/#Reading_a_Range_of_Cells_to_an_Array). Regarding storing information about the format of a cell you need to try something on your own and maybe open  a new question because that might be more complicated. And please be more [specific and concise](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) othwerwise your question will be voted down